# Show enlarged picture when mouse hovers above data point R

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, mouse

I am trying to plot a scatter plot that when the mouse hovers over one of the points, an image, corresponding to a URL in the data appears.

Is it possible in R? it seems it is possible in python...

thanks,

Comment: maybe the plotly package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the *Highchater* package:

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = rep(0, 4),
                 package = c("dplyr", "shiny", "purrr", "stringr"),
                 urlimage = c("https://github.com/rstudio/hex-stickers/raw/master/PNG/dplyr.png",
                              "https://github.com/rstudio/hex-stickers/raw/master/PNG/shiny.png",
                              "https://github.com/rstudio/hex-stickers/raw/master/PNG/purrr.png",
                              "https://github.com/rstudio/hex-stickers/raw/master/PNG/stringr.png"))

hover_info <- tags$tr(
  tags$th("Package"),
  tags$td(paste0("{point.package}")),
  tags$img(src = "{point.urlimage}", width = "125px", height = "125px"))  %>%
  as.character()

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df, 
                mapping = hcaes(x = x, y = y), 
                type = "scatter",
                marker = list(radius = 5, symbol = "circle")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    useHTML = TRUE,
    headerFormat = "<table>",
    pointFormat = hover_info,
    footerFormat = "</table>"
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, your code looks really awesome! 

few notes: 
1) it seems it does not work "as is" on my system. i get this error:
 Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'tags' not found.

if i miss something obvious or havend downloaded all the right libraries, please change your code to adress this issue. 
2) also I will appriciate if you explain more about tags$td(paste0("{point.package}")) notation.

Comment: Did you install `highcharter` package? It should work.

About the `tags` it is a way to customize your hover stuff. For a full detailed explanation about tags go to (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/).

`{point.variable}` is the way I am showing which part of the code I want to show in each tag. For example on the tag `img` I want to show the image that is in the variable `urlimage`. Then `{point.urlimage}`.

Comment: thanks, it actually failed to install the highcharter package, since XML install failed. I used "sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev" and it worked. 
however, for some reason the pictures still fail to load.  if you have any intuition as why it may happen please let me know :)
I use UBUNTU 18

Comment: Try to open in a browser.